# How to read an Excel spreadsheet and convert units?

Tags: python, excel, converters

I've got an excel spreadsheet that I would like to use python to convert the measurements from cm3/day to just cm3/year.

is there a way to do this?
I've looked into openpyxl mostly as this module seems to come up the most for excel editing but I guess I'm mostly confused about how to edit the units so they are all the same... I can't seem to find a module that supports what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You can read the column as string and replace 'cm3/sec' to 'cm3/year'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with pandas. You may need to install xlrd:
`pip3 install pandas xlrd`
or just save your file as csv.

```py
import pandas as pd
# Read the file with read_csv() or read_excel()
df = pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx', index_col=0)  # Your index is the first column
>>> df
         measure  amount
precip                  
1        cm3/day      45
2        cm3/day     132
3       cm3/year    9565
4        cm3/sec       5
5        cm3/day      67
6        cm3/day      52
7        cm3/sec       2
8        cm3/day      78
9        cm3/sec       3
10       cm3/day      92
```

Then you can use apply() to check and update values as you want. This will apply any function to each line of a pd.DataFrame with option axis=1. The applied function receives a line of your data as pd.Series object.
Let's define a function:

```py
def _update(serie):
    val = serie['amount']  # The original value
    volume, time = serie['measure'].split('/') # The time unit
    # Check and update
    if time == 'year':
        return serie
    elif time == 'day':
        serie['amount'] = val * 365
    elif time == 'hour':
        serie['amount'] = val * 24 * 365
    elif time == 'sec':
        serie['amount'] = val * 3600 * 24 * 365
    # Update measure col
    serie['measure'] = 'cm3/year'

    return serie
```

Then apply the function:

```py
new_df = df.apply(_update, axis=1)
>>> new_df
         measure     amount
precip                     
1       cm3/year      16425
2       cm3/year      48180
3       cm3/year       9565
4       cm3/year  157680000
5       cm3/year      24455
6       cm3/year      18980
7       cm3/year   63072000
8       cm3/year      28470
9       cm3/year   94608000
10      cm3/year      33580

# Save de new file:
new_df.to_excel('new_file.xlsx')
```

Hope this will help !

Comment: Can you post the error ? I guess it's because of your measure column (you'll have to check everything related to this field, you could need str.strip( ) ; I mean the error could be in "if time == "...

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in "*.xlsx" format you can read the file in python like this:

```py
#first import necessary packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_excel(file_name)
```

If in "*.csv" format do this:

```py
#first import necessary packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv(file_name)
```

To perform a calculation on a column(cm3/day/sec--this format I don't get but if you had cm3/day you could convert it yo cm3/year by the below code)

```py
#first check the type of your column
data["column"].dtype

#based on what you get as type

#If your column's data type is string
#convert it to integer
data["column_name"] = data["column_name"].astype(int)
#convert it to float
data["column_name"] = data["column_name"].astype(float)


# if your column is already of numeric type don't change it

#to convert cm3/day to cm3/year
data["column_name"] = data["column_name"]*365
```

PS: I can't see the linked image so I couldn't use the valid column names in the excel sheet

Comment: hi, thanks for your response! sorry my posting was a bit unclear, I had meant the records showed cm3/day and cm3/sec and I want to convert them all to cm3/year. I tried re-adding the image so hopefully it is visible now.

Comment: @avocado23 if your column values are in cm3/day you can multiply the column with 365( like the above code) and it will give you cm3/year. The problem with the image on my side is where I live imgur is blocked :/ Maybe you can use this website(https://imggmi.com/)  to upload your image and convert it to a link then you can add your image to your question like this : ![image_name](image_link you get from the website). To upload your image click overview browse image in your laptop and click upload now the you will get many links but you can use the first one)